# how to calculate prefix product in efficient way?

Tags: python-3.x, product

I have learnt that cumulative product can be stored with the help of factors, in this question the element range is too high , so for storing the least prime factors only takes 10^18. but the given time limit is 0.5 sec . how can I calculate prefix product in an efficient way? or How can solve this question in better way?

question is

```
calculate min of |(a[1]*a[2]*----a[x]) - (a[x+1]*a[x+2]*---a[n])|
```

where `x` is any index in the given array a?

i tried naive product which gave me memory limit exceeded

given memory limit 256 mb

Comment: Where is the code attempt you made to solve it!

Comment: actually array size given is 1 to 10^5 and its values range is 1 to 10^18 . so i could not think of optimal solution with these constraints. It was in a contest , so it was gone . actually I need optimal approach with those constraints.